# PHP Multiple file upload with multiple inputs

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload, input

I'm new to PHP. Now i have a problem with files upload.
All files are moved, but It didn't store file's name to database.
and it didn't show error. I have no idea to fix this one. Please help me out.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?insert_ads" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="b1" id="b1"/>

    <b>Link</b></br>
    <input type="text" id="b1l" name="b1l" class="form-control"/></br>

    <b>Home Small</b> <b style="color: blue;">100 x 100 px</b></br>
    <input type="userfile" name="b2" id="b2"/><br>

    <b>Link</b></br>
    <input type="text" id="b2l" name="b2l" class="form-control"/></br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish"/>

</form></br>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $b1 = $_FILES['b1']['name'];
    $tmp1 = $_FILES['b1']['tmp_name']; 
    $b1l = $_POST['b1l'];
    $b2 = $_FILES['b2']['name'];
    $tmp2 = $_FILES['b2']['tmp_name'];
    $b2l = $_POST['b2l'];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp1,"ads/$b1");
    move_uploaded_file($tmp2,"ads/$b2");

    $insert_posts = "insert into ads (b1,b2) value ('$b1','$b2')";
    $run_posts = mysql_query($insert_posts);
}
?>
```

Comment: you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), you have absolutely **NO** error handling on your db calls. you have absolutely no error checking on your uploads. in both cases you're simply assuming nothing could ever go wrong, which is very very very poor coding practice. never ever assume success. assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Do you have somewhere code where you are connecting to the database? Can you also put it here? And how does your table ads look like in DB?

Comment: You have a typo. Use `valueS` in your query.   `$insert_posts = "INSERT INTO ads (b1,b2) VALUES ('$b1','$b2')";`

Comment: Thanks for all your information :D Now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding any issues about using `mysql_query` or injection attacks, there are a number of things that could be going wrong here.

One option is that the query is executing, but you haven't assigned the `$b1` and `$b2` variables correctly.  This would be the case if rows are being added to the database, but the rows are empty (e.g., `SELECT b1, b2 FROM db.ads`" returns rows of `'',''`); in that case, you probably just aren't extracting the `name` attribute from the $_FILES variable correctly.  You can run `var_dump($_FILES);` to see more information about it and figure out what you need to get.

Another possibility is that the query is not executing.  Again, this may be for a couple of reasons -- maybe (somehow) it's not reaching that point in the code.  You can test that like so:

```
$insert_posts = "insert into ads (b1,b2) value ('$b1','$b2')";
echo $insert_posts; // if this shows up, you're running the next line also
$run_posts = mysql_query($insert_posts);
```

Another option is that your [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) level is not capturing an error.  A likely cause of this is that you have not connected to the database -- according to the [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) documentation...

> If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

A E_WARNING level error will allow the program to continue to execute unless you have configured your program to behave differently.

Finally, you may have a syntax error (and indeed it seems you do -- `VALUES`, not `VALUE`); according to the documentation, `mysql_query` returns `false` on error -- it does not throw an error.

You can rig it to do so by testing for false and using the `mysql_error` function to get the error:

```
$run_posts = mysql_query($insert_posts);
if ($run_posts === false) { 
  trigger_error("Error in SQL!\n" + mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR); 
}
```